# Use of watch to update image displayed in linux every N seconds fails

Tags: linux, watch

I have some codes that automatically generate Machine Learning plots on a server, sending plots to IoT clients at appropriate times for display.

The data pipeline works. However, my attempt to update the image in near real-time when a new plot is push is not working.

Currently my approach is:

```
user@client:~/data_viz $ watch -n3 feh -F plot0.png --zoom 200
```

where `feh` is some arbitrary lightweight Linux image viewer.

The problem is that even when the file (`plot0.png`) is overwritten successfully the viewer does not update until you kill it and restart it.

Update: I've acheived the world's worst version of this with the Bash approach below. The only problem now is that it flashes the desktop every second and will undoubtedly cause a seizure if I don't fix that...

```
$ watch -n2 sudo bash watch.sh
```

where `watch.sh` is

```
#!/bin/bash
i="0"    
while [ $i -lt 4 ]
do
pkill feh
sleep 1
feh -F plot0.png --zoom 200&
sleep 1
pkill feh
done
```

There also seems to be no way to actually break the infinite loop even with Esc and ctrl+c. I want the loop to be infinite, but I also would prefer to be able to interrupt it when I have to.

Comment: Well, you are thinking in the right direction. Once you open an image in `feh` (which is an excellent tool), it itself (like just about every other image viewer/editor) doesn't watch for changes in the source-file. However, `feh` does provide the `-R, --reload int` option to automatically reload an image after a given number of seconds. (see: `man 1 feh`)

Comment: You need to add the number of seconds `-R 5` (for 5 second refresh)

Comment: OK, sure, give me a minute and I'll write it up `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `feh`, like most image viewers/editors, does not watch the image-file for changes and automatically reload if changes occur, it does provide the `-R, --reload <int>` option that will cause `feh` to reload the image after the number of seconds specified as `<int>` transpire. For example:

```
feh --reload 5 image.png
```

will cause `feh` to reload `image.png` every `5` seconds. `man 1 feh` explains:

> ```
> -R, --reload <int>
>
> Reload filelist and current image after int seconds. Useful for viewing 
> HTTP webcams or frequently changing directories. (Note that the filelist 
> reloading is still experimental.)
>
> If an image is removed, feh will either show the next one or quit. 
> However, if an image still exists, but can no longer be loaded, feh 
> will continue to try loading it.
> ```